# How to make use of webhook input

Tags: python, stripe-payments, pytest, webhooks, fastapi

I am trying to make a test that will send data to a third-party service.

This service receives the data and pings my webhook. So this part works nicely. However, in order to close the loop, I would have to receive these webhook triggers in my pytest environment. So it might look as follows

```
@pytestmark
async def test_user(client, session, monkeypatch):
    app.dependency_overrides[current_user] = lambda: user1
    await client.post('/user/')

    # wait for the webhook outside of the test, which does receive the response from our third-party service

    # do some tests based on the processing of the webhook
```

Does somebody know how to do it? I mean, I could mock it via monkeypatch, but I do not want to do it here.

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this? I have the same question.

Comment: Hi @fergbrain sadly, I did not find a decent solution. But in case you found one, I would be happy to know about it.